# HBase NoServerForRegionException

Tags: hbase, biginsights

While trying to put to HBase through Java API, NoServerForRegionException is getting thrown.

Code Snipplet :

```
Put rowData;

  rowData.add(Bytes.toBytes(columnfamilyName),
                            Bytes.toBytes(key), Bytes.toBytes(val));
                        table.put(rowData);

 table.put(rowData);
```

The following error is appearing.

> Hbase:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException:
>   Unable to find region for ,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.>

From the command line using HBase Shell, if we try use put command, the same is working fine.

Also from the zookeeper logs, it seems that it is able to connect to HBase, and after which teh exception is getting thrown

Tried in IBM BigInsights Distribution.

Any thoughts on how to overcome this is highly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

EDit:

I am invoking this from a web server(Hosted in a different machine in same network as that of BigInsights Cluster) by specifying the ip and quorom details.

Comment: did your hbase-site.xml is configured properly?

Comment: Yes. As performing scan, put, list..are working through hbase shell

Comment: but did the hbase shell and your java program uses the same hbase-site.xml

Comment: In the java program, we only specify the quorom, hbase address and it uses the configured hbase-site in that.

Answer (score 1):

This error shows that your client is not able talk to the RegionServer. Please make sure it is running fine and there is no port or other network related issue. Try to dig the RegionServer logs for the exact error. Also point your web browse to **HBase WebUI(hmaster_machine:60010)**  and see if you are able to see the RegionServer over there.

Also, add the hostname/IP of your HBase machines into the etc/hosts file of your client machine.

Comment: I am able to see that RegionServer is running in port 60010 from the BigInsights UI